# ExtJS Combobox not loading up in Panal

Tags: json, combobox, cgi, extjs4.1

I have this panel view. Please check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNSCk/3/) . So I have a cgi script which returns json for combo-box value and label but its not loading up in combo-box. I am not sure why any help will be appreciated. I just want the options to show up each time combo-box drop down menu is clicked.

```
var incidentjreader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({},['cid','list']);
    var incident_store = new Ext.data.Store({
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                    url: 'test.cgi'
            }),
            reader: incidentjreader
    });

        var incident_combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        store: incident_store,
            mode: 'local',
            id: 'incidentcombo',
            typeAhead: false,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            width: 130,
            fieldLabel: 'Incident',
            valueField: 'cid',
            displayField: 'list',
            emptyText: 'Select Incident...',
    });

    incident_store.load();
```

Please check JSFiddle for more mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `ExtJS3.x` syntax and 4.x API, use appropriate release examples to get you started.

Here is the same fiddle with fixed syntax and a few modifications: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/QNSCk/4/